# set only 1 level depth by default instead of showing all in d3-hierarchy

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I went through this code

https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092

and i am getting

[image]

but i want

[image]

what i want is, to set only one level depth by default, for example

```
            ------Level 2: A
Top Level -|
            ------Level 2: B
```

. if i click to child node (Level 2:A), then it should show 1 level depth again for the child node and it goes on.

below is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/youngminds/vq74nehb/1/

Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look how the `click` functions toggles the tree, we can use that logic to alter the initial values.

So the `click` functions toggles the data from `children` to `_children`, we can apply that to the `treeData` to get the desired outcome:

Change `children` to `_children` were you want the tree to be hidden by default

---

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "_children": [{
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "_children": [{
          "name": "Son of B",
          "parent": "Level 2: B"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of B",
          "parent": "Level 2: B",
          "children": [{
              "name": "Son of B",
              "parent": "Daughter of B"
            },
            {
              "name": "Daughter of B",
              "parent": "Daughter of B"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];



// ************** Generate the tree diagram    *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.y, d.x];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  //nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    (d.depth === 1) ? d.y = d.depth * 100: d.y = d.depth * 150;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i know it is silly question to ask, but i am not able to figure out, where exactly you made changes on code to get the first result. would please let me know?

Comment: I've renamed the keys inside `treeData` of the elements you want to hide. First it was `children`, I've changed 2 to `_children`

Comment: got it. thank you for you help! Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little too old. But here is one more option (using v7). This is useful for any custom childarray name.

```
root = d3.hierarchy(rawdata, (d) => d.customChildArray);
root.descendants().forEach((d) => {
    if (d.depth >= _this.options.initialDepth) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    }
}
```

This could be useful if you are getting any input data, and don't want to meddle with the input.